# An inequality in two variables

Tags: real-analysis, functions, inequality

This problem was proposed by D. Popescu (Rumania) y M. Amengual (Spain) to a Spanish rewiew.

Let $x,y$ be real numbers such that $$\sqrt{x^2-3x} + \sqrt{y^2-3y}=1$$ Prove that $$x^2+y^2\lt2(x+y) +15$$
I gave a solution in which the constant bound $15$ was improved to $8$ and ensuring that there is a number $c\in [7,8)$ satisfying the inequality and open the question about  if $ c$ could be maybe equal to the integer $7$.

I would like to know this. Thanks you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $u := \sqrt{x^2-3x} = 1 - \sqrt{y^2-3y}$. Then $0 \le u \le 1$ and
$$
   x^2 - 3x = u^2 \, , \quad y^2 - 3y = (1-u)^2 \tag 1
$$
Solving this for $x$ and $y$ gives
$$
  x = \frac 32 \pm \sqrt{u^2 + \frac 94} \le \frac 32 + \sqrt{u^2 + \frac 94} \, , \\
  y = \frac 32 \pm \sqrt{(1-u)^2 + \frac 94} \le \frac 32 + \sqrt{(1-u)^2 + \frac 94} \, .\tag 2
$$
From $(1)$ and $(2)$ we get
$$
 x^2 + y^2 - 2(x+y) = u^2 + (1-u)^2 + x + y \\
  \le u^2 + (1-u)^2 + 3+ \sqrt{u^2 + \frac 94} + \sqrt{(1-u)^2 + \frac 94} \tag 3 \, .
$$
The rhs  of $(3)$ is a convex function of $u$ and symmetric with respect to $u = \frac 12$, therefore the maximum is obtained at $u = 0$ and $u=1$.
The maximum value is
$$
 C := \frac 12 (11 + \sqrt{13}) \approx 7.30278 \, .
$$
So we have
$$
 x^2+y^2 \le 2(x+y) + C
$$
with equality for $x = 3$ and $y = \frac 12(3 + \sqrt{13})$ (or vice versa).

Comment: Your answer is the same that the one given by Samuel Gómez Moreno (Universidad de Jaén, Spain). The mine is more “analytic” and I will write later.